# How to view/monitor which events are being fired from controls on a user interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am creating an GUI using winforms in C#, all the controls have numerous events. I would like to know which of these events are being fired and when. One way would be to put debug statements on each of the event handlers but that would require too much work. Is there any way of doing this in Visual Studio 2008/2010 or are there any tools that can help?

Comment: You could probably use reflection to search all the controls, find their events, and hook up a handler that dumps diagnostic info. That wouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed Spy has possibility to log all events of chosen control. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) where 
you can read about this tool and download it.

Comment: This looks good, however having problems compiling and running it on Vista 64 with VS 2010. Getting error: `Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedSpyLib, Version=1.0.3877.33621, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: I believe this is really problem with 64bit system. The injection of Managed Spy code into your program should be different on such system. Unfortunately I don't know whether there is some 64bit version, all i can advise it to try 32bit, e.g. on virtual machine

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer as it looks like exactly what I need even though I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) with the monitoring filter "Module == System.Windows.Forms.dll && Function == On*" will show what events are firing for all winforms controls.

Comment: Looks like a good app, however you should read the stackoverflow FAQ:

"May I promote products I am affiliated with here?

Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable;"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some information overload, you could use Spy++ (\Common7\Tools\Spyxx.exe) to see all the windows messages generated by the application.

Some of the window messages translates more or less directly to .net events...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a logging class that subscribes to these events and write the event plus the time stamp into a log file.

It still requires that you write some code, but it's independent of your production code and shouldn't affect it any way.

Comment: is it possible to subscribe to every single event all in one go or individually? Not so bothered about logging them as I am more interested in finding out which events are fired and when so that I can use or handle them if required.

Comment: @Piers - you'll have to subscribe to them individually I'm afraid. I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted to do - hence the logging suggestion.