# Detecting where event comes from

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with a control. It is firing an annoying onMouseOver event and I don't know where it is coming from. I, for sure, did not hook it up. I did several experiments, one of them being actually implementing the onMouseOver event and setting the "Handled" flag to true and it still was firing. I think it was firing AFTER my own fired because the handled flag should have taken care of it?? I also did a search for "focus" and "mouse" in my code and nothing came back. Is there any way in VS2010 to detect where an event came from so I can actually fix it?
thanks

Comment: How do you know its firing the event? if you have a mouse over event check the sender or put a breakpoint and check the call stack

Comment: Winforms, webforms, wpf, what?

Comment: If this is a custom control you could modify the event to use the add...remove syntax, then put a breakpoint on the add.

Comment: It is a WPF control. It is actually working as an extension of an desktop application. In other words, we are extending an Application licensed to our company and basically we are embedding the control. I know it is firing the event because as soon as I move the mouse over the control, the entire window gets focused.

Comment: Luis, is this "event" an actual method in your code thats firing? or just seemingly random

Comment: Sayse, it is random. I did not add the event. There is nothing in the code I can see would produce a mouse over event. I actually checked the call stack with my own onMouseOver event. Nothing shows... because it happens after that... crazy...

Comment: but *what* is it doing? is it showing a tip text or something?

Comment: How do you know it's `OnMouseOver` and not `OnMouseEnter` or one of the other similar ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running, you can try opening up Spy++ from the tools menu.  You should then be able to see the list of messages.  This should give you a mechanism for seeing what is responsible for the stray mouseover messages.  It is possible that the base code is sending the windows message, even if the mouse is not actually hovering etc.

I think some are referring to this as Managed Spy, but it looks the same:

See article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

reference: [How to view/monitor which events are being fired from controls on a user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477960/how-to-view-monitor-which-events-are-being-fired-from-controls-on-a-user-interfa)