# What event is fired when user right clicks a TextBox and clicks Paste?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know what event is fired when the user rights clicks in a TextBox and clicks Paste?  I'm trying to capture the Paste so I can mimic what happens when the TextChanged event is fired from the TextBox by the user typing.

Comment: The TextBox control does not provide built-in events for distinguishing between typing, pasting, or other ways of text input. You could maybe capture right-click and create your own context menu, and handle when paste is clicked. You'd also need to handle ctrl+v too. Another option could be to use the windows api to detect when windows paste event happens.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477960/how-to-view-monitor-which-events-are-being-fired-from-controls-on-a-user-interfa

Comment: What are you trying to do with the pasted text?

Comment: You can handle WM_PASTE in a Custom Control, set a variable, check the state of that variable in the TextChanged event -- You can use `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)` if you want to know what's being pasted in

Comment: @LarsTech I have a Save button on my form that I want to enable once any field is edited.  The TextChanged event (and KeyPress) covers when a user types into the TextBox.  Ctrl+V is covered by KeyPress.  I can't figure out how to know when the user pastes text in via the default ContextMenu that Windows displays when right clicking in the TextBox.  So I don't care WHAT is pasted in to the field, but rather that it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi mentioned, you can add a `PasteDetected` event to a `TextBox` using a simple customization, and (if you choose) intercept it to prevent the paste from occurring.

```
class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PASTE:
                var e = new PasteDetectedEventArgs();
                PasteDetected?.Invoke(this, e);
                if (e.Cancel)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    public event EventHandler<PasteDetectedEventArgs> PasteDetected;
}

public class PasteDetectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}
```

Once detected, you could just check the `Clipboard` to see what the content is (if this is something you care about).

[image: intercept paste]

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox.PasteDetected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;    // Disallow the paste.

        // Putting the cancel option in the event argument carries a risk, so
        // do 'not' do anything in this handler that would block WndProc!!!
        BeginInvoke(()=>MessageBox.Show(Clipboard.GetText(), "Paste Detected"));
    };
```

*This WORKS for context menu paste.*

Comment: To clarify a bit further, I have a Save button on my form that I want to enable once any field is edited.  The TextChanged event (and KeyPress) covers when a user types into the TextBox.  Ctrl+V is covered by KeyPress.  I can't figure out how to know when the user pastes text in via the default ContextMenu that Windows displays when right clicking in the TextBox.  So I don't care WHAT is pasted in to the field, but rather that it happened.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Edited accordingly!